# How to remove unused css/javascript from website?

Tags: html, css, performance, optimization, pagespeed

I have a site which has too many unused CSS and JS files. From google developer tools I got to know how to detect unused CSS/JS files. But my problem is there is a `style.css` file which has 24000 lines of code and a `bootstrap.css` file which has 9000 lines of code. It is nearly impossible to go to each line remove styles, can anyone suggest a better way to remove those styles.

Comment: Well, you can google search for any online tool. Not sure how accurate it will be, but you can try https://purifycss.online/

Comment: Create a backup before doing all these just to be on the safe side..